# Dagger 2: Inject dependency issue when change code from Java to Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have *Dagger 2* setup in my *Android* (in *Java*) project.

I have `MyModule`:

```
@Module
class MyModule {
   @Provides
   static Lorm provideLorm() {
      ...
   }
}
```

I have another class `Bar` which has `Lorm` being injected:

```
public class Bar {
   @Inject
   private Lorm lorm;

   @Inject
   public Bar() {
   }

   public void doTask() {
     lorm.makeIt();
   }
}
```

Then, I have a 3rd class named `Foo`, it has `Bar` as dependency:

```
class Foo {
  // I inject Bar
  @Inject
  private Bar bar;

  // I also make Foo to be injectable to other class
  @Inject
  public Foo()

  public void doIt() {
      bar.doTask();
  }
}
```

It works. With above setup, I can instantiate Foo by `Foo foo = new Foo(); foo.doIt();` and dagger can inject the dependency for me.

Now I want to switch them to *Kotlin*.

I tried :

```
class Bar @Inject constructor(private val lorm: Lorm) {
    ...
}

class Foo @Inject constructor(private val bar: Bar) {
    fun doIt()=bar.doTask()
}
```

But now if I want to create an instance of Foo, I can't do :

```
val foo = Foo() // compiler complains that I need to pass a instance of bar.
```

So, what is the correct way to let dagger to inject the dependency `bar` for me like how it behaves in Java version so that I can still do `val foo = Foo()` and call function `foo.doIt()`?

Comment: `Foo foo = new Foo(); foo.doIt();` would cause a `NullPointerException`: you're ignoring Dagger entirely and just creating a `Foo` yourself, so `bar` is uninitialized.

Comment: You need to get an instance of Foo from the Dagger component instance, instead of instantiating it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should either let *Dagger* create an instance of `Foo` through the *Dagger Module* with the *@Provides* annotation or do it manually with `Foo(Bar(Lorm(...)))`.

And as you use *Dagger* it is reasonable to stick to the 1st option.